# load a component only once throughout the app

Tags: react-native

Starting my first rn learning project and stuck somewhere else. Basically, after user logs in, I want to display a text at the top.

IDComponent.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';

const IDComponent = () => {
 //generate the ID
  const id = generateId();
  return (<View><Text>{id}</Text></View>);
};

export default IDComponent;
```

After user logs in, I display the component in all my screens like this:

ScreenHome.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

const ScreenHome = () => {

  return (
       <View>
           <IDComponent/>
       </View>
  );
};

export default ScreenHome;
```

ScreenFormP.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

const ScreenFormP = () => {

  return (
       <View>
           <IDComponent/>
       </View>
  );
};

export default ScreenFormP;
```

I want IDComponent() to be called only once essentially. I tried the following but it doesn't load the component at all:

```
      const [isLoadedAlready, setLoadingState ] =useState(false)

      if (isLoadedAlready){
            return null;
        }
       setLoadingState(true);
       return(<Text>{generateId()}</Text>)
```

but that makes the compnoent never to render at all.

Alternatively, is there a way to do once:

ScreenContainer.js

```
     <IDComponent>
     <OtherScreensPlaceHolder>
```

in which all other screens would populate in ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are rendering the same component on different page. You can try two different things. as the props or navigation changes its tends to re-render the whole component including the component you want to load only once.

You can try the layout system, make a global layout component like layout.js and put the IDComponent on the top. and pass all other pages as props on the component.

You can get an idea about persistent layout patterns from [here](https://adamwathan.me/2019/10/17/persistent-layout-patterns-in-nextjs/).

Or in react native in the navigation page put the component on top so its always on top on ScreenContainer.js file.

Also try out the PureComponent and useMemo on the component for avoiding rerender.

Hope this helps, If not working let me know.